# Eslint padding-line-between-statements and class members

Tags: eslint

Is there any way to use class members as statement types for the ESLint rule `padding-line-between-statements`? I want to have blank spaces between each method and the constructor. The `function` statement type does not work.

Also, is there a way to make the same rule ignore `export` statements and use the rule that would have applied if there was no `export`? I want an `export const ...` to behave the same way as `const ...` and I want `export class ...` to behave the same as `class ...` (`class` declarations require a blank space above whereas `const` declarations do not).

Comment: It's helpful to include in your post the same style of *Correct/Incorrect* examples that are in the eslint documentation. I can't tell what you are trying to do based on your explanation. Separately, it seems that you are asking two unrelated questions in one post. This discourages people from answering because their answer will not be accepted if they can answer only one of the two questions. You're artificially constraining the possibility of receiving any kind of answer by asking two questions in one post.